# When adding a task to Google Cloud Tasks from a Google Cloud Run Instance I get Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

[UPDATE] adding fallback: true to the cloud task client did resolve the issue for me actually.

`const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });`

I have a cloud run instance that is iterating over a list of strings and saving things to a db, and also adding a task to cloud tasks. The weird thing is, it's doing it ten times, and only the first one always fails with this error. The rest of the calls work.

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
2023-06-08 19:31:03.165 CST
at callErrorFromStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.14/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
2023-06-08 19:31:03.165 CST
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.14/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
2023-06-08 19:31:03.165 CST
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.14/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
2023-06-08 19:31:03.165 CST
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.14/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
2023-06-08 19:31:03.165 CST
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.14/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
```

```
async function addTask(task: any, url: string) {
    try {
        if (!url) {
            throw new Error('Must specify a HTTP URL for the task');
        }

        return client.createTask({
            parent,
            task: {
                httpRequest: {
                    httpMethod: 'POST',
                    url,
                    oidcToken: {
                        serviceAccountEmail,
                    },
                    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
                    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(task)).toString('base64'),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        Log.error('Error adding task: ', err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

```
const getPostsWithPagination = async (
    baseUrl: string,
    postId: string | null = null,
    page: number,
    maxPages: number,
): Promise<any[]> => {
    try {
        const query = `${baseUrl}${postId ? `?after=${postId}` : ''}`;
        const body = await fetchJson(query);

        if (!body || !body.data || !body.data.children) {
            throw new Error('Invalid response from fetchJson');
        }

        const posts = body.data.children;

        for (const post of posts) {
            const p = await savePost(post.data);
            // this line
            if (p) await addTask(post.data.permalink, URL);
        }

        if (page <= maxPages - 1) {
            return posts.concat(await getPostsWithPagination(baseUrl, body.after, page + 1, maxPages));
        } else {
            return posts;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        Log.error('Error in getPostsWithPagination:', err);
        return [];
    }
};
```

I've tried cpu boost on startup, having a sleep for 5 seconds so the task client would connect..